# how to display uploaded image in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

i am trying to display my uploaded image in my view please anyone here to help me

**controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'another' => '',
        'caption'=> 'required',
        'image' => ['required', 'image',],
    ]);
    $imgpath=request('image')->store('uploads','public');
    $post = new Post([
        'caption' => $request->get('caption'),
        'image' => $request->get('imgpath'),
    ]);
    $user = Auth::user();
    $post = $user->posts()->create($request->all());
    $user->posts()->save($post);

    return redirect('/profile/'.auth()->user()->id);
}
```

**this is what i use in my view**

```
 <div class="row pt-4">
        @foreach($user->posts as $post)
            <div class="col-4">
                <img class="w-100" src="/storage/uploads/{{$post->image}}">
            </div>
        @endforeach

    </div>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exacly problem do You have? What error? Was image uploaded to storage? What was saved (if was saves) to database under "image" column?

Comment: the image is not showing in the view but a showing a broken image

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that this image is saved and it is saved in the desired directory try to use storage_path().

```
    @foreach($user->posts as $post)
        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="w-100" src="{{storage_path('uploads/' . $post->image)}}">
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

@Harout FMD is right. upload() method accepts two params. The second one specify the directory and since your param is 'public' the asset() method should do the work

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you!

```
@foreach($user->posts as $post)
        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="w-100" src="{{asset('storage/'uploads/' . $post->image)}}">
        </div>
    @endforeach
```